In Azure Data Factory (ADF), there seems to be a discrepancy where linked services are not syncing between live mode and Git mode
I deployed my Azure Data Factory (ADF) from the dev environment to the staging environment using Azure DevOps. When in live mode, All the services in the ADF staging are just like they were in the dev environment. However, after configuring Git with the staging branch, I noticed that some linked services were missing. In the live mode, I have four linked services, but in the staging branch, there are only two. I attempted to import resources, but it didn't resolve the issue. What could be causing this discrepancy?
Screenshot attached .



Hi @Rudra, have you checked my answer below? If you are configuring git in Staging with the same repo as DEV and use the same collaboration branch?

I can reproduce your issue using the following steps.

Create Linked services in DEV live mode.
Publish all in DEV git mode.
Deploy from DEV to Staging using DevOps pipeline with "ARM template deployment" task.
Delete some Linked services in DEV git mode. In my case what was deleted was the SQL server.
Config git in Staging with the same repo as DEV and use the same collaboration branch.
In Staging, I can see SQL server was deleted in git mode but still existed in live mode.


If you don't "Config git in Staging with the same repo as DEV and use the same collaboration branch.", please go to the repo of your Staging ADF and check if all linked services are in the linkedService folder in your collaboration branch.
According to the official doc Best practices for CI/CD,

Git integration. Configure only your development data factory with Git integration. Changes to test and production are deployed via CI/CD and don't need Git integration.

There is no need to config git for your Staging if you have used CI/CD pipeline. If your Staging does require git, it is recommended that you use a new repo, or at least a new collaboration branch.
